Trying to send a debug message whenever my bot is trying to DM a member with their dm's turned off, discord.py (first post)
I'm trying to send an embed describing the error whenever my bot dm command, but it just goes straight to the error, without sending the embed.
Here's my code for the error event:
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError(Forbidden)):
        emb = Embed(title="Error : Forbidden",
                    description="Couldn't use the command, probably because you tried to DM someone with their DM's off",
                    color=0xFF0000)
        emb.add_image("https://media1.tenor.com/m/5lbcs68aI2MAAAAC/anime-sad.gif")
        await ctx.send(embed=emb)

and for my dm command :
@client.tree.command(name="dm", description="DM's someone!", guild=GUILD_ID)
async def dm(interaction: discord.Interaction, user: discord.Member, message: str):
    em = Embed(title=f"Here's a message from {interaction.user.display_name}!",
               description=message,
               color=0x00FF00)
    em.set_footer(text='Answer them by using /dm !')
    await user.send(embed=em)
    await interaction.response.send_message("DM sent!")

I'm using discord.py latest update, and python 3.10.8

Need an error handler for your app (slash) commands? These are handled on the CommandTree. You can set one using the decorator or subclass it.
Documentation

CommandTree.on_error
CommandTree.error (decorator)

How
from discord import app_commands, Interaction, Forbidden

bot = commands.Bot(...)
# Bot has a built-in tree
tree = bot.tree

# this will function as a global error handler for app commands
@tree.error
async def tree_on_error(
    interaction: Interaction,
    error: app_commands.AppCommandError
):
    error = getattr(error, 'original', error)
    if isinstance(error, Forbidden):
        emb = Embed(
            title="Error : Forbidden",
            description="Couldn't use the command, probably because you tried to DM someone with their DM's off",
            color=0xFF0000
        )
        emb.set_image(url="https://media1.tenor.com/m/5lbcs68aI2MAAAAC/anime-sad.gif")
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=emb)


Works like a charm, thanks! Just a small easy error this game me is that on the emb.add_image, i had to do : emb.set_image(url="https://media1.tenor.com/m/5lbcs68aI2MAAAAC/anime-sad.gif")
